# No resource found that matches the given name 'MaterialTheme'

Tags: android

i added 
`circleimageview-2.1.0 glide-3.7.0 google-material-typeface-3.0.1.0.original materialdrawer-5.8.2` to dependencies.

This's my buid.gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':circleimageview-2.1.0')
compile project(':glide-3.7.0')
compile project(':google-material-typeface-3.0.1.0.original')
compile project(':materialdrawer-5.8.2')
```

Here's my error's:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Android Studio : [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)
Or Xamarin                 : [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/)

Try this examples and watch out for the syntax of it.

Comment: Or if your syntax is good try to do a Project Syncronise and Rebuild.